# Best and Efficient way of creating C++ struct like things in JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have one JSON data which I have written in my JS code as

```
let CreateIssueFormData = (function() {
    return {
        "fields": {
            "project": {
                "key": "NC"
            },

            "issuetype": {
                "id": ""
            },

            "components": [{
                "id": ""
            }],

            "summary": "",

            "description": "",

            "labels": [],

            "timetracking": {
                "originalEstimate": "1w",
                "remainingEstimate": "5d"
            }

        }
    }
});
```

and I'm using it as

```
let formData = new CreateIssueFormData();
formData.fields.issuetype.id = reqParams.issuetype;
formData.fields.components[0].id = reqParams.component;
formData.fields.summary = reqParams.summary;
formData.fields.description = reqParams.description;
```

I've first created the class like data-structure so that whenever I need it I will instantiate a object and give that instance it's values.

Also declaring the struct like give a sense of what should be there in my object.

**QUESTION:**

1. Is it a good way to do in javascript?
2. Any other efficient way for  doing this?

I've started JS few months back and earlier I was coding in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, it's useless to have a function returning an object's skeleton. A better use of that function is to pass it reqParams:

```
let CreateIssueFormData = function(reqParams) {
  // if reqParams is null, use an empty object
  reqParams = reqParams || {};

  return {
    "fields": {
      "project": {
        "key": "NC"
      },

      "issuetype": {
        "id": reqParams.issuetype || "" // after the || is the default value if issueType is null/undefined, you can put what you want
      },

      "components": [{
        "id": reqParams.component || ""
      }],

      "summary": reqParams.summary || "",

      "description": reqParams.description || "",

      "labels": [],

      "timetracking": {
        "originalEstimate": "1w",
        "remainingEstimate": "5d"
      }
    }
  }
};

// this will have some fields with values
let formData = new CreateIssueFormData(reqParams);

// this is a skeleton only with no values
let emptyFormData = new CreateIssueFormData();
```

Now, the function is useful and saves you legwork.

Comment: Yeah.... I like the idea. Also my target of using my JSON like this is to make my function body smaller. I hope using this style add one more purpose.

Comment: reqParams = reqParams || {};           Will this statement creates a clone or just a reference to pass argument to this function????

Comment: No, it doesn't create a clone, it's a safety to check if reqParams has indeed been received. It's the same as `if (reqParams == null) reqParams = { }`. As you probably know, all parameters are optional in Javascript so sometime you have to check if you really received the parameters or not. The parameter is passed by value so there is no reference problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easily the best way to do it in Javascript. Javascript doesn't have Structs, so using objects in this case is definitely the most efficient way to do this.

Now if it's the best way really depends on what you want to do with it, for example you could also use a class if you prefer that style of syntax. However classes do not work for ES5 or below.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

In your case, you can create a constructor:

```
let CreateIssueFormData = function() {
  this.fields = { 
    project: {
      key: "NC" 
    }
  }
}

let formData = new CreateIssueFormData()
formData.fields.project.key = reqParams.key
```

Comment: I have one question... How to I add private members, If I use the above pattern?

Comment: you can have private methods by declaring them as variables (with `var` or `let`) inside the constructor. in this case they will not be exposed, so you will achieve encapsulation.